# How to recursivly create pedigrees and find matches for inbreeding detection (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm stumped creating a function in Oracle to find out wether 2 mating animals will create inbreeding.
Function should take 3 parameters: male ID, female ID and depth to look into.

At first I think it I should create two pedigrees using data from a table with a structure like this:

```
    TABLE animal
    +-----+---------+--------+
    | ID  | SIRE_ID | DAM_ID |
    +-----+---------+--------+
    | 111 | 112     | 212    |
    | 112 | 113     | 213    |
    | 212 | 116     | 216    |
    +-----+---------+--------+
```

(Not entirely relevant, but for this and future examples I am using ID-s as 1?? is male and 2?? is female.)
For this I should use the depth parameter - probably recursivly.

This is what I have so far:

```
function animal_pedigree (p_id number,
    p_max_pedigree_level number,
    p_pedigree_level number := 0,
    p_position varchar2 := '') return animal_ancestors_table
    pipelined
is
    v_sire_id number;
    v_dam_id number;
        v_row animal_ancestor;
begin
        v_row.id := p_id;
        v_row.pedigree_level := p_pedigree_level;
        v_row.position := p_position;
    pipe row (v_row);
    if p_pedigree_level < p_max_pedigree_level then
        select sire_id, dam_id
        into v_sire_id, v_dam_id
        from arc.animal
        where id = p_id;
        if v_sire_id is not null then
            for rec in (select id, pedigree_level, position
                from table(animal_pedigree (v_sire_id, p_max_pedigree_level, p_pedigree_level+1, p_position || 's'))) loop
                                v_row.id := rec.id;
                                v_row.pedigree_level := rec.pedigree_level;
                                v_row.position := rec.position;
                pipe row (v_row);
            end loop;
        end if;
        if v_dam_id is not null then
            for rec in (select id, pedigree_level, position
                from table(animal_pedigree (v_dam_id, p_max_pedigree_level, p_pedigree_level+1, p_position || 'd'))) loop
                                v_row.id := rec.id;
                                v_row.pedigree_level := rec.pedigree_level;
                                v_row.position := rec.position;
                pipe row (v_row);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end if;
    return;
end;
```

After that comes the tricky part for me: comparing the pedigrees to find matching ID-s (and also remembering the depth at which the match was found).

Eventually I would like to return the smallest depth at which the inbreeding was found or 0 when none was found.

NB! I would like to compare only the two pedigrees, not compare ID-s inside one. (I want it to be ignored if inbreeding was already present, only interested in new forming inbreeding.)

To further illustrate I'm adding 3 examples.
Matches marked with * (asterisk).

Example 1:

Male pedigree

```
Depth           1       2       3

                            |--114
                    |--113--|
                    |       |--214
            |--112--|       
            |       |       |--115
            |       |--213--|
            |               |--215
       111--|
            |               |--117
            |       |--116--|
            |       |       |--217
            |--212--|
                    |       |--118
                    |--216--|
                            |--218
```

Female pedigree

```
Depth           1       2       3

                            |--124
                    |--123--|
                    |       |--224
            |--122--|       
            |       |       |--125
            |       |--223--|
            |               |--225
       211--|
            |               |--127
            |       |--126--|
            |       |       |--227
            |--222--|
                    |       |--128
                    |--226--|
                            |--228
```

[RETURN 0] No identical ID-s found

Example 2:

Male pedigree

```
Depth           1       2       3

                            |--114*
                    |--113--|
                    |       |--214
            |--112--|       
            |       |       |--115
            |       |--213--|
            |               |--215
       111--|
            |               |--117
            |       |--116--|
            |       |       |--217
            |--212--|
                    |       |--114*
                    |--216--|
                            |--218
```

Female pedigree

```
Depth           1       2       3

                            |--124
                    |--123--|
                    |       |--224
            |--122--|       
            |       |       |--125
            |       |--223--|
            |               |--225
       211--|
            |               |--127
            |       |--126--|
            |       |       |--227
            |--222--|
                    |       |--128
                    |--226--|
                            |--228
```

[RETURN 0] Matching ID-s are both found in male pedigree. Ignore.

Example 3:

Male pedigree

```
Depth           1       2       3

                            |--114*
                    |--113--|
                    |       |--214
            |--112--|       
            |       |       |--115
            |       |--213--|
            |               |--215
       111--|
            |               |--117
            |       |--116--|
            |       |       |--217
            |--212--|
                    |       |--118
                    |--216--|
                            |--218
```

Female pedigree

```
Depth           1       2       3

                            |--124
                    |--123--|
                    |       |--224
            |--122--|       
            |       |       |--125
            |       |--223--|
            |               |--225
       211--|
            |               |--127
            |       |--114*-|
            |       |       |--227
            |--222--|
                    |       |--128
                    |--226--|
                            |--228
```

[RETURN 2] Matching ID-s found at depth of 3 in male pedigree and at depth of 2 in female pedigree

Comment: Your examples are helpful in understanding the problem. To help all of us test our tentative solutions, it would also be helpful to add a `create table as select ...` statement to reproduce the sample data in an actual table.

Comment: You can do find the result using a recursive CTE. It should be much simpler than a procedure.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm running oracle 10(g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on 10g rather than an newer version, you'll need to use oracle's hierarchical queries instead of the recursive common table expressions shown by The Impaler.  For my solution to work it's helpful to encode the animal gender as a separate column rather than embedding it in the animals ID, so I'll use the following table definition. (Note: I don't have a 10g instance to try this on so I don't know for sure if defferable constraints are available in 10g or not. if not just remove those clauses. They made it easier to load sample data.):

```
CREATE TABLE animal
    ( ID number not null primary key
    , GENDER varchar2(1) not null
    , SIRE_ID number
    , DAM_ID number
    , constraint animal_gender check (gender in ('M','F'))
    , constraint animal_sire_fk FOREIGN KEY (sire_id) REFERENCES animal(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    , constraint animal_dam_fk FOREIGN KEY (dam_id) REFERENCES animal(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    );
```

From there it's helpful to generate a mapping of all ancestors for any given animal, this is called a closure table and you can google more about closure tables if desired.  This is done either with recursive SQL or in our case with oracle hierarchical tables since you're on 10g. I'll name it Ancestry for this example:

```
with ancestry as (
select CONNECT_BY_ROOT id id
     , CONNECT_BY_ROOT gender gender
     , id ancestor_id
     , gender ancestor_gender
     , level-1 lvl
  from animal
  connect by id in (prior sire_id, prior dam_id)
)
```

From there you can find all animals with common ancestry through a moderately simple join:

```
select m.id sire_id
     , f.id dam_id
     , m.ancestor_id
     , m.ancestor_gender
     , m.lvl sire_lvl
     , f.lvl dam_lvl
  from ancestry m
  join ancestry f
    on m.ancestor_id = f.ancestor_id
   and m.gender = 'M'
   and f.gender = 'F';
```

That query lists all pairs of male and female animals, and all their common ancestors. It's a bit much, and we'll want to pare it down to just the pairings you're interested in, and limit it to just the first common ancestor.  To do that we'll add a where clause limiting it to the pairing(s) of interest and use aggregations to get us down to just the first ancestor:

```
select m.id sire_id
     , f.id dam_id
     , max(m.ancestor_id) keep (dense_rank first order by least(m.lvl,f.lvl)) first_ancestor
     , max(m.ancestor_gender) keep (dense_rank first order by least(m.lvl,f.lvl)) ancestor_gnder
     , min(m.lvl) sire_lvl
     , min(f.lvl) dam_lvl
  from ancestry m
  join ancestry f
    on m.ancestor_id = f.ancestor_id
   and m.gender = 'M'
   and f.gender = 'F'
 where (m.id, f.id) in ((111,211))
 group by m.id, f.id;
```

Putting it all together here's the final query:

```
with ancestry as (
select CONNECT_BY_ROOT id id
     , CONNECT_BY_ROOT gender gender
     , id ancestor_id
     , gender ancestor_gender
     , level-1 lvl
  from animal
  connect by id in (prior sire_id, prior dam_id)
)
select m.id sire_id
     , f.id dam_id
     , max(m.ancestor_id) keep (dense_rank first order by least(m.lvl,f.lvl)) first_ancestor
     , max(m.ancestor_gender) keep (dense_rank first order by least(m.lvl,f.lvl)) ancestor_gnder
     , min(m.lvl) sire_lvl
     , min(f.lvl) dam_lvl
  from ancestry m
  join ancestry f
    on m.ancestor_id = f.ancestor_id
   and m.gender = 'M'
   and f.gender = 'F'
 where (m.id, f.id) in ((111,211))
 group by m.id, f.id;
```

And you can see it in action with this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a580cff8a6642313155294a07ae24be1&hide=2) in the fiddle example ancestry data was generated with the example # in the most significant place in the animal ID, and only the ancestries that differed from example 1 were entered for examples 2 and 3, so for example 2 only the male line was added and in example 3 only the female line was added yeilding the following pairings (1111, 1121), (2111, 1211), and (1111,3211) for examples 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

This will only return records when the pair of animals have common ancestors.  It also pregenerates the entire ancestry closure which could be time consuming for large adjacency lists. For a more efficient query, the ancestry closure can be limited to just the animals of interest with a START condition. Further the depth of search can be limited in one of two places (or both), in a where clause in the output query, or a where clause in the ancestry query. Additionally to meet your requirement that pairings return a row showing a level of zero when there are no common ancestors some slight modifications are required.  First off, the ancestors CTE needs to be modified to have a null level for the self join (depth zero). This will be important for making the aggregates work. Then the aggregate columns and the join criteria need to be updated slightly to allow records with no common ancestors.  Here's the modified query:

```
with ancestry as (
select CONNECT_BY_ROOT id id
     , CONNECT_BY_ROOT gender gender
     , id ancestor_id
     , gender ancestor_gender
     , case level when 1 then null else level-1 end lvl
     , level-1 lvl0
  from animal

 -- Limit depth to 3 generations
 where level-1 <= 3 

 connect by id in (prior sire_id, prior dam_id)

 -- Only build ancestry closure for these animals
 start with id in (1111,1211,2111,3211)
)
select m.id sire_id
     , f.id dam_id
     , max(nvl2(m.lvl,m.ancestor_id,null)) keep (dense_rank first order by least(m.lvl,f.lvl) nulls last) first_ancestor
     , max(nvl2(m.lvl,m.ancestor_gender,null)) keep (dense_rank first order by least(m.lvl,f.lvl) nulls last) ancestor_gnder
     , nvl(min(m.lvl),0) sire_lvl
     , nvl(min(f.lvl),0) dam_lvl
  from ancestry m
  join ancestry f
    on (m.ancestor_id = f.ancestor_id or (m.id, f.id) in ((m.ancestor_id, f.ancestor_id)))
   and m.gender = 'M'
   and f.gender = 'F'
 where (m.id, f.id) in ((1111,1211) -- First example no common ancestors
                       ,(2111,1211) -- 2nd ex common ancesters in male line
                       ,(1111,3211))-- 3rd ex common ancestry of sire & dam

   -- Limit to at most 3 generations
   and greatest(m.lvl0, f.lvl0) <= 3

 group by m.id, f.id;
```

Comment: I do not get it. This does not give any results in either the SQL Fiddle or in my database. It just keeps running... Could the reason be that it tries to build the whole ancestry? My database is quite big (millions of animals) with ancestry going in depths of 10 and more. Maybe I read the query wrong, but I don't see the limit for the depth of the ancestry built and does it create the ancestry for all animals before selecting from it?

Comment: I'm not sure why the SQL Fiddle isn't working, I'm having issues with it right now too, so perhaps it's an issue on their end.  That aside, yes the current query builds the entire ancestry closure, and also doesn't limit the depth of search..  You can optimize the ancestry by adding a depth limit and limiting which animals it searches on.  I've updated the last query above with those enhancements.  Another option is to create the ancestry closure as a materialized view so that it doesn't need to be rebuilt for every query.

Comment: I moved the sample from SQL Fiddle to db<>fiddle which seems to be more stable, at least for the moment.

Comment: Thank you Sentinel. The solution worked, but I think I have to take use of your idea of building the materialized query as even with a depth of 4 and limiting the query for just 2 animals it took about 10 seconds to get the result. And in my case I need to populate a list of about a hundred pairings on a single page with the resulted number. So I'll accept your answer as it gives the desired result. Thanks for guiding me towards the correct path :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Recursive CTE to find the matching ancestors.

This example is untested since you didn't provide the scripts to create the sample data. Anyway, this query should work:

```
with
l (id, aid, sire_id, dam_id, lvl) as (
  select id, id, sire_id, dam_id, 0 from animal where id = 111 -- male ID
  union all
  select l.id, a.id, l.lvl + 1
  from l
  join animal a on a.id in (l.sire_id, l.dam_id)
),
r (id, aid, sire_id, dam_id, lvl) as (
  select id, id, sire_id, dam_id, 0 from animal where id = 211 -- female ID
  union all
  select r.id, a.id, r.lvl + 1
  from r
  join animal a on a.id in (r.sire_id, r.dam_id)
)
select 
  l.id as male_id, l.aid as male_ancestor_id, l.lvl as male_ancestor_depth,
  r.id as female_id, r.aid as female_ancestor_id, r.lvl as female_ancestor_depth
from l
join r on r.aid = l.aid
```

This query return ALL matches (there can be multiple), in all its combinations. You can add extra changes to remove duplicate matches, since an animal can be ancestor of multiple ones already on each tree.

Also, the main query shows all the details of the matches including the matching ancestors and their corresponding depths. You can easily modify it to show only the depth (as you wanted). Or... you can expand it to show you the "full path" to get to each ancestor. It depends on the exact output you would prefer. I bet once you see the result, you'll want more information about it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm running oracle 10(g)